# telnetlib execution not responding and timing out

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I've been trying to connect to a telnet service via telnetlib for a few hours now. I've been trying to use telnetlib to read content and interact with the remote service. I've been using this code for testing purposes (with Python version 3.9)

```
import telnetlib

HOST = "horizons.jpl.nasa.gov"
port = "6775"                                                                                                                                                                              

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.open()                                                                                                                                                                            

print(tn.read_until("Horizons> "))
tn.write("x\r")
tn.close()

print(tn.read_all())
```

I expected seeing the welcome screen and prompt of the JPL Horizons system-the prompt is "`Horizons>` ", at which point I wanted the program to enter the exit code "x" and enter. However, instead the program is unresponsive, printing nothing to the terminal and timing out (`TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out`). The error log indicates that the error is from the `create_connection` function of `telnetlib.py`, specifically `sock.connect(sa)`.
Is there something wrong with my code? How can I ensure the connection is made and the output of the service is printed for use?

If not: is there any other way to automate telnet communication and read output with Python?

**-=UPDATE=-**
replacing the initial `tn.write(b"x\r")` with another command, trying to actually get some content and info out of the connection:

```
tn.write(b"sun\r")
tn.read_until(b" Select ... [E]phemeris, [F]tp, [M]ail, [R]edisplay, ?, <cr\
>:")
tn.write(b"x\r")
tn.read_until(b"Connection closed by foreign host.")
info = tn.read_until(b"Connection closed by foreign host.")
tn.close()
print(info)
print(tn.read_all().decode("utf-8"))
```

just prints until the first prompt, not entering `sun\r` (or at least, not printing the result) and then doesn't end the program, leaving me stuck on the 'Horizons> " prompt.

Comment: See the update to my answer, which addresses your updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using your `port` variable anywhere, so `telnetlib` is trying to connect to port 23. Try this:

```
import telnetlib

HOST = "horizons.jpl.nasa.gov"
port = "6775"                                                                                                                                                                              

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, port)
print(tn.read_until(b"Horizons> "))
tn.write(b"x\r")
tn.close()

print(tn.read_all())
```

Note also that you need to provide bytes instead of strings to the telnetlib functions.

---

### Update 1

It looks like you should be sending `\n` to terminate commands rather than `\r`. The following code works for me:

```
import sys
import telnetlib
import time

HOST = "horizons.jpl.nasa.gov"
port = "6775"                                                                                                                                                                              

with telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, port) as tn:
    tn.read_until(b"\r\nHorizons> ")
    tn.write(b"sun\n")
    data = tn.read_until(b" Select ... [E]phemeris, [F]tp, [M]ail, [R]edisplay, ?, <cr>:")
    tn.write(b"x\n")
    tn.read_all().decode("utf-8")

print('--- data ---')
print(data.decode())
```

Comment: Well, looks like @kichik beat me too it by 20 seconds... :)

Comment: works great! the one issue i have with that solution is that the output printed in the terminal is filled with interstitial `\r\r\n` which makes it difficult to read. i'm pretty sure the `\r\r\n` should be printed as a new line, but how come it's being printed verbatim?

Comment: Because this code is printing the `bytes` object. If you decode the bytes into a string (`print(tn.read_all().decode())`), it will render as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the port. You also didn't pass the right parameters to `open()` or pass bytes as required by the library. Here's a working example.

```
import telnetlib

HOST = "horizons.jpl.nasa.gov"
port = 6775

with telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, port) as tn:
                                                                                                                                                                            
    print(tn.read_until(b"Horizons> ").decode("utf-8"))
    tn.write(b"x\r")
    tn.close()

    print(tn.read_all().decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: damn, it's that simple, wow. i think part of the [multiple] errors i've run into were caused by inputting strings rather than bytes—i wasn't aware of how string-to-byte conversion worked. this works perfectly, I think. thank you!